# how to get respected person details saved in arrays from selected value in table view

Tags: iphone

i am having 3 arrays with info regarding peoples.

one array is with name,second array with email,third array with phone number.

eg:{jon,Willems...},{jon@example.com,Willems@example.com...},{123456,123456,...}

I need to display agent names in table.

when ever i selects people name in table i need to retrieve that particular person email and phone number.

how can i done,can any one please post some code or tutorial.

Thank u in advance.

Comment: i did n't get how can i retrieve email and phone Number values by selecting  names

Comment: Do you already have your datasource set up and running with your `UITableView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In didSelectRowAtIndextPath get the indexPath value

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView  *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath
{
[email objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[phoneNumber objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

**EDIT:**

The Above code assumes that a user is associated with a single email, phone number

If a user name is associated with many email, phone numbers use NSDictionary or Custom Object.

Comment: i need to get phone number also